# ICE in clang++ with is_invocable_v / is my code valid?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

The following code fails to compile with clang (core dump / ICE) - but it compiles fine with gcc and msvc.
Is my code valid? Can I change something that would work with current clang version.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void Func() {
    }
};

struct B {
    static void Func() {
        std::cout << "Hello from struct \n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
void Do(){
    auto lambda = [](auto&& cls) -> decltype(
       std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(cls)>>::Func()
    ) {};

    if constexpr (!std::is_invocable_v<decltype(lambda), A>){
        std::cout << "no static Foo\n";
    } else{
        T::Foo();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Do<A>();
    Do<B>();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The idea of this code is to detect if for example `S::Func()` is a valid expression.

Comment: I created a bug report: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47119

Comment: A "ICE" (Internal Compiler Error) should never happen due to a bug in your code. That's (with 99.9% certainty) a bug in the compiler.

Comment: I agree but I don't understand what `std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(cls)>>::Func()` is supposed to do. With `auto lambda = [](auto&& cls) -> decltype(cls.Func()) {}` the `lambda` _will_ be invokable with an `S`.

Comment: If `Func()` would be a static method is_invocable_v should return true - but in this case false.
`S::Func()` is an invalid expression...

Comment: @Bernd Aha, I didn't understand that's what you actually wanted.

Comment: Yes, I use this for compile-time reflection....

Comment: I see. I think you can leave `is_invocable_v` out though. Just putting `lambda(S());` in the code makes the compiler barf too.

Comment: The point is that the compiler should not "barf". I update the code to see it better...

See it here @godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/bzesr9

Comment: Here a better version which compare templates and lambdas: https://godbolt.org/z/WG6q9T